# osascript Expected end of line but found class name?

Tags: terminal, applescript

Not really sure what its expecting here, I assume its around `click button` though. This used to work on 10.10.3, but seems to have stopped on 10.10.4?

Script

```
function AcceptSecurity ()
{
osascript <<EOF
  tell application "System Events"
    repeat while exists (processes where name is "SecurityAgent")
      tell process "SecurityAgent"
        click button "Allow" group 1 of window 1
      end tell
      delay 0.2
    end repeat
  end tell
EOF
}
```

Exact error `165:170: syntax error: Expected end of line but found class name. (-2741)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

> ```
> click button "Allow" group 1 of window 1
> ```

is missing an ‘of’

```
click button "Allow" of group 1 of window 1
```

If the button isn’t in a group, omit the group completely

```
click button "Allow" of window 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This works

```
tell process "SecurityAgent" to click button "Allow" of window 1
```

Comment: I prefer this style for single statements anyway, +1